# In Dune, how much did spice cost for a non-Arrakis citizen?

Tags: novel, dune

I'm taking about the original book, before the Atreides took over. Was spice only for the mega rich? Could a middle class Caladan citizen for example buy it?

Comment: I'm not sure that Frank Herbert ever discussed the economics of the spice, at least not anything involving numbers. It was only the cosmopolitical generalities (e.g. " the spice must flow") that mattered. Also, when you say "original book", are you excluding any [prequels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_prequel_series) such as "Prelude to Dune", written by other authors ?

Comment: I believe I have to accept prequels here, even though I generally don't like to, because my question is about pre-Dune economics

Comment: @Spencer I have a vague memory of a line mentioning something like that a tablespoon of Spice could buy you a house on the Guild Sanctuary planet of Tupile.  I'm trying to find it again, but if right, it was certainly out of the price range of the ordinary person.

Comment: @suchiuomizu That would depend on what a typical dosage/strength was.  Maybe I don't need to buy the equivalent of a house.  Maybe just the equivalent of a sofa might suffice me.

Comment: Basically a dupe of [What was the typical dose of Spice-Melange?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141002/20774)

Comment: I think the answer to that question is good for mine and I see that Valorim copied it here. But I don't think it's a duplicate because the two questions ask different things

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky - Generally if a question can be answered by an identical answer, that's usually a pretty good sign that they're duplicates, even if they're asking something in a different way.

Comment: As this is now closed as a duplicate, I've deleted Valorum's redundant/self-plagiarised answer. If the question is reopened (and I'm following this question, so I should be alerted) I might reconsider, but I'd expect if the question is significantly different enough it should have a significantly different enough answer from that previous dupe target.